# How to use LIKE Operation on specified column name and value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

How to search only on specified column using like operation

*Sample code won't work*

```
DECLARE @COL_NAME VARCHAR(30) = 'EMAIL'
DECLARE @COL_VALUE VARCHAR(100) = 'xyz@so.com'

SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = @COL_NAME AND 'COL_NAME' LIKE '%' + @COL_VALUE + '%'
```

Comment: Wanting to parametrise column names usually indicates a broken data model. Why do you have multiple columns containing the same "type" of data?

Comment: I want to implement search where a user can choose a specific column @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Usually a limited/lazy query generator.. not necessarily model: ie. user can be "well normalized" with Name, Email, etc. but the query generator doesn't use 'an existing library/approach that makes this easy' D:

Comment: Then you may wish to read [Dynamic search conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html). One important point to note is that we usually *keep* separate parameters for each queryable column. This means that we can continue to use the *right* data types when querying, which avoids a) inefficient queries and b) the mess that comes from coercing everything into a string and then (often) hoping that the string gets converted back into the right data type without any formatting issues (which were introduced by forcing the intermediate string form)

Comment: The rebuttal comment was *not* against the implication that this 'wish' often hides another issue; it was merely challenging the assertion that the (data) model is itself "broken". Access to the data- sure.

Comment: @user2864740 - I didn't say it was *always* broken. I said it was *usually* broken (and in fact my second comment was more directed back to dchennaraidu). Because I've far more often seen this type of question in a context where it turns out we have `Email`, `Email2`, `Email3`, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use parameterized SQL and additionally wrap `@COL_NAME` in `QUOTENAME()` in order to prevent SQL injection:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @COL_NAME sysname = 'EMAIL'
DECLARE @COL_VALUE VARCHAR(100) = 'xyz@so.com'

SET @SQL = N'
    SELECT *
    FROM SOMETABLE
    WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@COL_NAME) + ' LIKE ''%@COL_VALUE%''';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL, N'@COL_VALUE VARCHAR(100)', @COL_VALUE = @COL_VALUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape literal single quotes.  One way to do this is to double them up:

```
DECLARE @COL_NAME VARCHAR(30) = 'EMAIL'
DECLARE @COL_VALUE VARCHAR(100) = 'xyz@so.com'

EXEC ('SELECT * FROM SOMETABLE
WHERE ' + @COL_NAME + ' LIKE ''%' + @COL_VALUE + '%''')
```

Comment: The first statement seems non-sequitur. The "solution" has 100% to with EXEC / executing dynamic SQL, and nothing to do with quotes (except to convert it to use EXEC..)